# Check if directory exists without having permissions to directory

Tags: vba, validation, directory

I'm using the below code to have a user provide the path to an SFTP directory for recording in an inventory of such vendor projects. I'm hitting an issue populating the path for a project where I know the directory exists, so I'm 99% sure that the issue is I don't have permissions to the directory (which I know I don't).

```
'Check if the SFTP exists already
If MsgBox("Does the SFTP for this vendor/campaign already exist?", vbYesNo, "SFTP Exists?") = vbYes Then
    'Prompt for the network folder
    Do While SFTP = ""
        SFTP = Trim(InputBox("Please provide the folder path to the report's SFTP.", "New Campaign/Vendor SFTP", " "))
        
        Select Case SFTP
            Case "", " "
                If MsgBox("No path provided for the new campagin/vendor SFTP folder. Would you like to retry providing the SFTP (clicking 'No' " & _
                        "will leave the SFTP folder field empty for now).", vbYesNo, "No Value Provided") = vbNo Then
                    SFTP = "ignore"
                Else
                    SFTP = ""
                End If
                
            Case Else
                'Potentially valid folder, check if it exists already
                If Dir(SFTP, vbDirectory) = "" Then
                    'Provided path doesn't exist, prompt user to retry
                    If MsgBox("The specified path (" & SFTP & ") does not exist. Would you like to retry providing the SFTP (clicking 'No' " & _
                        "will leave the SFTP folder field empty for now).", vbYesNo, "Create the Folder?") = vbYes Then
                        SFTP = ""
                    Else
                        SFTP = "ignore"
                    End If
                End If 'the folder exists no action needed
                
        End Select
    Loop
Else
    'Set SFTP to ignore so that we leave the field blank downstream
    SFTP = "ignore"
End If
```

In particular I get run-time error 52.

Is there a way to use `DIR`, or something like it, to check that the directory exists **without needing permissions to the folder**?

I'd like to keep that validation to avoid things like typos messing up the inventory sheet (further down the path is used to create link in the sheet, which a bad path obviously would mess up), but I can't always be sure that the person who will be filling in the path has access to the folder.

Comment: Referencing "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" .. Not sure ..Check if this works ... `Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject ...
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject` and then `If fso.FolderExists(FolderPathHere ending with \) Then`

Comment: [Link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object)

Comment: Naresh, if you want to put that as the answer, that'll be great :) Get you your credit

Comment: Was not sure if it would work on restricted folder access.. so mentioned as comment.. :).. Please accept/ upvote the answer only if it works, so others will know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" ..

Not sure ..Check if this works ...

```
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
```

and then you can check if the folder exists using..

```
If fso.FolderExists(FolderPathHere ending with \) Then
```

Comment: One small tweak to the logic I forgot to mention: 
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Comment: @JMichael .. great.. happy to learn that .. thanks